# “unexpected error : bash unexpected end of file” from code with command in curly braces (group command)

Tags: bash

I expected this file to echo "error" and exit. Why does it produce the unexpected end of file error instead? I used vim to create the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

{ eval "nothing" } || { echo "error" ; exit 1 }
echo "something"
```

Comment: http://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`}` is only special in command position. In your code, each `}` is just another argument to the preceding `eval` and `exit` commands. Nothing ever closed the opening `{`.

You need to first terminate the preceding commands explicitly, for example, with a `;`.

```
{ eval "nothing"; } || { echo "error" ; exit 1; }
echo "something"
```

Comment: What is a *command position* and is the `}` in `{ if :; then :; fi }` also in command position?

Comment: Command position is the part of the simple command where the name of the command goes. Basically, it's the first word in the command that isn't an assignment. `}` is in command position, because `fi` itself is a reserved word (when itself in command position) that the parser knows does not take any arguments, and so is "self-terminating".

Comment: The concept of command position is what lets you write `echo fi` without it being a syntax error, or use `fi` as a variable name.